# Laravel 5.0 saves image as damage or corrupted with custom Filsystem

Tags: php, laravel

I am saving an image after upload with ajax but the image gets saved as damaged.

My disk

```
'blockcontentimages' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => public_path() . '/static/core/img/templates',
],
```

How I store my image:

```
$image = $request->file('content');

$file = $image->getClientOriginalName();
$fileName = '/static/core/img/templates/' . $blockNewsletterPivotId . '_' . str_replace(' ', '_', $file);

Storage::disk('blockcontentimages')->put($fileName, $image);
```

dd of $image:

```
UploadedFile {#27
  -test: false
  -originalName: "cloud.jpg"
  -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
  -size: 54754
  -error: 0
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here why it's being saved as a damaged or corrupted file.

### EDIT

When I try to open the saved file I get this error message in my photo viewer:

> Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupted, or is too large.

Comment: What do you mean by damage/corrupted? Didn't get what was the issue!

Comment: when I try to open the saved file i get this error message in my photo viewer: Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupted, or is too large.

Comment: Are you using post method? And also using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ?

Comment: Since 5.3 you can use the `store()` function. Have you tried it? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#file-uploads

Comment: I know you got the answer but I suggest you to use 'imagick' instead of 'gd' in /config/image.php. imagick is better.than gd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `file_get_contents` method in order to get **image** :

Try like :

```
Storage::disk('blockcontentimages')->put($fileName, file_get_contents($image));
```